# Write Lack-of-fit Sum of Squares in Quadratic Form

Tags: regression, linear-algebra, multivariate-regression

Let

\begin{equation}
SSLF = \sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}(\bar{y_{i}} - \hat{y_{i}})^{2}
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}(\bar{y_{i}} - \hat{y_{i}})^{2} = n(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}})'(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}})
\end{equation}

where $n = (n_{1},...,n_{m})$

and

\begin{equation}
n(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}})'(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - \hat{\overrightarrow{y}}) = n(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - H\overrightarrow{y})'(\bar{\overrightarrow{y}} - H\overrightarrow{y})
\end{equation}

where $H$ is the Hat matrix.

I believe I need to work it down to

\begin{equation}
\bar{\overrightarrow{y}}'(I - H)\bar{\overrightarrow{y}}
\end{equation}

So that I can get the degrees of freedom as $m - (k+1)$ but I am having trouble doing that.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=idempotent.

Comment: @whuber sorry, how does that help?

Comment: The idempotence of $H$ leads to the desired result immediately: just expand the product.

Comment: I don't see how it does